# FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a user using createUserWithEmailAndPassword method as described in https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth. I have pretty much followed all steps, in my firebase console I have enabled "Email/Password" sign in method. 
Code

```
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mUserEmail, mPassword)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, ">>>>> createUserWithEmailAndPassword().onComplete() - Start");
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, R.string.log_error_occurred,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    mAuthProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.d(TAG, ">>>>> createUserWithEmailAndPassword().onComplete() - End");
                }
            });
```

Error:

> 02-06 21:23:38.508 30878-30878/com.labs.kavayah.scio W/CreateAccountActivity: signInWithEmail:failed
>                                                                                 com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Bad Request ]                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbix.zzcb(Unknown Source)                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbiu$zzj.zza(Unknown Source)
>   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbjf.zzcc(Unknown Source)                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbjf$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
>   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbja$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
>   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)

Not sure where I am going wrong.

project gradle

> playServicesVersion = '10.0.1'
>   firebaseClientVersion='2.3.1'

app gradle

> ```
> //firebase - start
> compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$rootProject.ext.playServicesVersion"
> compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$rootProject.ext.playServicesVersion"
> compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$rootProject.ext.playServicesVersion"
> compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$rootProject.ext.playServicesVersion"
> compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$rootProject.ext.playServicesVersion"
> compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:$rootProject.ext.playServicesVersion"
> compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$rootProject.ext.playServicesVersion"
> compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:$rootProject.ext.playServicesVersion"
> compile "com.firebase:firebase-client-android:$rootProject.ext.firebaseClientVersion"
> compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:$rootProject.ext.playServicesVersion"
> //firebase - end
> ```

Comment: It's not good practice to use the legacy Firebase SDK, `firebase-client-android`, with the new SDK, `firebase-database`, etc.  See if you get better results after removing `firebase-client-android`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@qbix I will be migrating old android client library code to new ones, thanks for pointing out. I am hoping that it will help others, the problem in my case was that I had 2 SHA fingerprint certificate, an old one and a new one, please ensure that whatever SHA key you are using in google project API console ensure firebase uses the same SHA fingerprint.

Once I removed the old one all working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Reporting what I went through:
`FirebaseException Internal error` normally occurs from a variety of reasons. It's just like `Syntax Error` in your terminal.
So to get a pretty better understanding, you'll need to read what comes after the square brackets `[]`.
For example `Could not validate certificate: Certificate not valid until` Occurs when your request is from an insecure port.
You'll need to ensure a secure connection to access your Firebase DB. Initially my device time was 5 years back, hence an insecure connection. I had to adjust my time and it worked.